# Powershell for Linux: Workaround for missing "out-gridview"?

Tags: linux, shell, powershell

In Aug 2016, Microsoft's Powershell went open-source.

However, there is no "out-gridview" option yet. The autocompletion feature
shows these Out* options

```
PS /mnt> dir | Out                                            
Out-Default  Out-File     Out-Host     Out-Null     Out-String   outocp
```

Note that there is no `Out-Gridview` at this time. Did I overlook a feature, commandlet that can do something similar?  Sometimes I'd ike to have my tabular data displayed in a sortable GUI Window (for showing something to windows users who are not used to command line windows).

My powershell

```
PS /mnt> $PSVersiontable           

Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
PSVersion                      6.0.0-alpha                                     
PSEdition                      Core                                            
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         
BuildVersion                   3.0.0.0                                         
GitCommitId                    v6.0.0-alpha.9                                  
CLRVersion                                                                     
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.
```

Comment: yep, not much of a surprise as it is built on top of .Net Core... aint Format-Table good enough?

Comment: I asked about this on the powershell gitter, the best explanation was "I don't think there are any WPF libraries ported to .net core or cross plat environs, which I believe out-gridview relies on."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/out-gridview-returns/

```
Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalTools
get-childitem | out-gridview
```

Comment: `The module ... 0.2.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalTools.psd1' requires a minimum PowerShell version of '6.2' to run.`

Answer (score 1):

This guy has built his own [partial replacement solution](http://blog.backslasher.net/open-gridview.html) in python, although it currently has some issues (installed but is throwing an error for me in a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04)

From a clean OS image:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install opengridview
```

It also does not currently support selections/output

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.PowerShell.GraphicalTools` is [currently not an option](https://github.com/PowerShell/GraphicalTools/issues/101). However the [same repository](https://github.com/powershell/GraphicalTools) now has [Out-ConsoleGridview](https://github.com/PowerShell/GraphicalTools/blob/master/docs/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools/Out-ConsoleGridView.md) and [Show-ObjectTree](https://github.com/PowerShell/GraphicalTools/blob/master/docs/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools/Show-ObjectTree.md). Install using `Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools`.